# How can I reverse the effect of apt-get build-dep <package>?

Tags: apt

When I run:

```
apt-get build-dep <package>
```

privileged it installs the build dependencies for `<package>`.

Now, I know that I can use `apt-cache depends <package>` to see *binary* dependencies. I haven't found any way to show the same information for *build dependencies* in a single command invocation, which I could then use to achieve what I want.

So, how can I reverse the effect of a `apt-get build-dep <package>`, i.e. remove the packages previously installed by an invocation of that command?

---

Braiam's answer below yields for the packages that are build dependencies:

```
autotools-dev
debhelper
dpkg-dev
libexpat-dev
libgd2-noxpm-dev
libgeoip-dev
liblua5.1-dev
libmhash-dev
libpam0g-dev
libpcre3-dev
libperl-dev
libssl-dev
libxslt1-dev
zlib1g-dev
```

The packages the complete `apt-get autoremove` wants to remove are:

```
build-essential debhelper dpkg-dev libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Especially `build-essential` isn't desirable here, but I can fix that on my own.

The actual list of packages that got installed were:

```
debhelper
dh-apparmor
gettext
html2text
intltool-debian
libcroco3
libgettextpo0
libpcre3-dev
libpcrecpp0
libssl-dev
libunistring0
po-debconf
zlib1g-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, no aptitude as I promised (the search terms are a mess) so we need to use the good old apt:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove $(apt-cache showsrc PACKAGE_NAME | sed -e '/Build-Depends/!d;s/Build-Depends: \|,\|([^)]*),*\|\[[^]]*\]//g')
```

Reference: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/undo-apt-get-build-dep-remove-build.html

Comment: This appears to work somewhat, but not reliably, going to edit my question with what that gave me.

Comment: `sudo apt-mark manual build-essential` will leave that package alone.

Answer (score 4):

Tumbleweed [writes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140835/how-to-uninstall-all-packages-installed-by-aptitude-build-dep#146562):

> For the future, I highly recommend using `mk-build-deps` ... instead of `aptitude build-dep`. That leaves a package ... in your system, [which has dependencies] on the build-deps, that you can easily uninstall later.

Answer (score 4):

So that packages you need don't get removed:

```
read -p "Enter package name: " packageName
sudo apt-mark auto $(apt-cache showsrc $packageName | sed -e '/Build-Depends/!d;s/Build-Depends: \|,\|([^)]*),*\|\[[^]]*\]//g' | sed -E 's/\|//g; s/<.*>//g')
sudo apt-mark manual build-essential fakeroot devscripts
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

However, you really should consider using `mk-build-deps` in the future to avoid this package trainwreck.